# Join tables to get sold products

Tags: magento

I am joining two tables 'sales/order_item_collection' and 'sales/orders' by 'order_id', so that afterward i can filter sold products by 'store_id' and 'product_name'

Here is the code:

```
$orderTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order');
$itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join(array('ord'=>$orderTable),'e.order_id = ord.entity_id');
```

Why is this join not working?

Thank you

Comment: click the checkmark to the left of the correct answer for some of your other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order item collection object implements `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract`, so looking at that class, the join method doesn't take an array for table (unlike some other collections). Also, you don't need to get the table manually, just specify the model and Magento will take care of the rest. So this works:

```
$itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id');
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank You... that helps a lot.

Here is my final code for getting sold products filtered by store, and time

Comment: $itemsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from'=>$dateStart,'to'=>$dateEnd))
->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id')
->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('eq'=>'1'))
;